# Can MongoDB MapReduce functions behave like CouchDB views?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, couchdb, document-database

The nice thing about CouchDB is that the view results are updated incrementally as the database changes. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with MongoDB? I've been unable to locate any specifics in the documentation. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? MongoDb has other capabilities that may not require the automatic view updating feature of CouchDb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MongoDB does not support dynamically-updated views in the way that CouchDB does. MapReduce results are written to a collection on disk and/or returned in the query; they are not updated unless you run the job again to do it.